# Disable CollapsingToolbar's ability to collapse on scroll

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like my collapsingtoolbar to only collapse in response to an onclicklistener, not scroll events. I'm not sure how to achieve this. I've been playing around with the scroll flags but can't come up with a solution. This is what my layout currently looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/CalorieDagger.AppBarOverlay"
    app:expanded="false"
    app:layout_behavior="com.example.jay.caloriedagger.ui.ScrollingCalendarBehavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:elevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/compactcalendar_view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">

            <com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
                android:id="@+id/compactCalendarView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                app:compactCalendarBackgroundColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:compactCalendarCurrentDayBackgroundColor="#FFC107"
                app:compactCalendarCurrentSelectedDayBackgroundColor="#BBDEFB"
                app:compactCalendarTextColor="#fff"
                app:compactCalendarTextSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/CalorieDagger.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/date_picker_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/centerInParent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/centerInParent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_picker_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/centerInParent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/date_picker_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/date_picker_text_view"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date_picker_text_view"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContentFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What about adding this line to `AppBarLayout`? `app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="?attr/actionBarSize"`